# How to send data from Python to Access when the database is linked to a SharePoint list?

Tags: python, ms-access, sharepoint

everyone!
I have an issue with my code where it performs web scraping and saves the data to an Access database. For this scenario, everything is working fine. The problem arises when I link this database to a SharePoint list or even to Dataverse, where it gives the following error:

> InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from datetime import datetime
import time
import threading
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc


#dsn = r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\user\python\WSInterface.accdb;'
#dsn = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\user\\python\\WSInterface.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;'
dsn = r'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\python\WSInterface.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;'

con = pyodbc.connect(dsn)



temp, combined_data, historic_data = get_data_and_classify()


cursor = con.cursor()
if not cursor.tables(table='Combine', tableType='TABLE').fetchone():
    cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE Combine (
            Data DATETIME,
            Av1a6 INT);
    """)


for index, row in combine_data.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO Combine (
            Data, Av1a6
        ) VALUES (?, ?);
    """, 
    row['Data'], row['Av1a6'])
    

if not cursor.tables(table='Historic', tableType='TABLE').fetchone():
    cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE Historic (
            Indice INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
            Av1a6 INT
        );
    """)


for index, row in historic_data.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("""
        UPDATE Historic
        SET Av1a6 = ?
        WHERE Indice = ?;
    """, 
    row['Av1a6'])


con.commit()
con.close()
```

I already have all the drivers installed on my computer, but the issue persists. Does anyone have any tips on what might be happening?

Comment: I think your connection string to pyodbc might be incorrect (I've never tried to use the driver you've used). Try setting up your sql connection string as Microsoft suggests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16